# Python - My frequency function is inefficient

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, frequency, coding-efficiency

I'm writing a function that returns the number of times appeared of a word that appeared the most in the list of words.

```
def max_frequency(words):
    """Returns the number of times appeared of the word that
    appeared the most in a list of words."""

    words_set = set(words)
    words_list = words
    word_dict = {}

    for i in words_set:
        count = []
        for j in words_list:
            if i == j:
                count.append(1)
        word_dict[i] = len(count)

    result_num = 0
    for _, value in word_dict.items():
        if value > result_num:
            result_num = value
    return result_num
```

For example:

```
words = ["Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Duck", "Duck"]
answer = max_frequency(words)
print(answer)

3
```

But this function is slow when dealing with large amount of words in a list, for example, a list of 250,000 words takes over 4 minutes for this function to present the output. So I'm seeking help to tweak this.

I don't want to import anything.

Comment: "I don't want to import anything." - thats nonsense. The stdlib is there for a reason. If e.g. `itertools` or `collections` has something appropriate and you don't use it you should feel bad because that makes you a bad programmer in that moment (only excuse is homework where you are not allowed to use the stdlib etc)

Comment: i think you either `don't want to import anything` or searching for performance, because these two statements are _almost always_ mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I fully agree with the comments related to your *I don't want to import anything* statement, I found your question amusing, so let's try it.

You don't need to build a `set`. Just go directly with `words`.

```
words = words = ["Happy", "Happy", "Happy", "Duck", "Duck"]
words_dict = {}

for w in words:
    if w in words_dict:
        words_dict[w] += 1
    else:
        words_dict[w] = 1

result_num = max(words_dict.values())

print(result_num)
# 3
```

Comment: Great use of dictionary, I never knew .values() existed

Answer (score 3):

To prevent multiple passes of your list for each unique word, you can simply iterate over it once and update dictionary values for each count.

```
counts = {}
for word in words:
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
```

**Outputs**:

```
>>> print(max(counts.values()))
3
```

---

That being said, this can be done much nicer using a `defaultdict` instead of `get` or using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)... limiting yourself to no imports in Python is never really a good idea if you have the choice.

For instance, using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(words)
most_common = counter.most_common(1)
```

Comment: ++ for `collections.Counter` example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code which is about 760% faster.

```
def max_frequency(words):
    """Returns the number of times appeared of the word that
    appeared the most in a list of words."""

    count_dict = {}
    max = 0

    for word in words:
        current_count = 0

        if word in count_dict:
            current_count = count_dict[word] = count_dict[word] + 1
        else:
            current_count = count_dict[word] = 1

        if current_count > max:
            max = current_count

    return max
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Data size similar to OP's

Let's start with a list of words

```
In [55]: print(words)
['oihwf', 'rpowthj', 'trhok', 'rtpokh', 'tqhpork', 'reaokp', 'eahopk', 'qeaopker', 'okp[qrg', 'okehtq', 'pinjjn', 'rq38na', 'aogopire', "apoe'ak", 'apfobo;444', 'jiaegro', '908qymar', 'pe9irmp4', 'p9itoijar', 'oijor8']
```

and compone at random these words to form a text

```
In [56]: from random import choice
In [57]: text = ' '.join(choice(words) for _ in range(250000))
```

#### Different methods are possible

From the text we can have a list of words in the text (note, `wl` is very different from `words`...)

```
In [58]: wl = text.split()
```

from this list we want to extract a dictionary, or a dictionary-like object, with a count of the occurrences, we have many options.

First option, we build a dictionary containing all the different words in `wl` and we set the value, for each key, equal to zero and later we do another loop on the list of words to count the occurrences

```
In [59]: def count0(wl):
    wd = dict(zip(wl,[0]*len(wl)))
    for w in wl: wd[w] += 1            
    return wd
   ....:
```

Second option, we start with an empty dictionary and use the `get()` method that allows for a default value

```
In [60]: def count1(wl):
    wd = dict()                   
    for w in wl: wd[w] = wd.get(w, 0)+1
    return wd
   ....:
```

Third and last option, we use a component of the *standard* library

```
In [61]: def count2(wl):
    from collections import Counter
    wc = Counter(wl)
    return wc
   ....:
```

## Is one method better than the others?

Which is best? the one you like the most... at any rate, here are the respective timings

```
In [62]: %timeit count0(wl) # start with a dict with 0 values
10 loops, best of 3: 82 ms per loop

In [63]: %timeit count1(wl) # uses .get(key, 0)
10 loops, best of 3: 92 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit count2(wl) # uses collections.Counter
10 loops, best of 3: 43.8 ms per loop
```

As expected, the fastest procedure is the one that uses `collections.Counter`, but I was a little surprised in noticing that the first option, that makes TWO passes over the data, is faster than the second one... my guess (I mean: guess) is that all the testing for new values is done while instantiating the dictionary, probably inside some `C` code.